# TYPO3 PHP Runtime Deprecation Notice:

Tags: php, exception, content-management-system, typo3, templavoila

i have a problem with some old TYPO3 stuff, i tried to make a old TYPO3 Website run on my Ubuntu system.
And sorry if somethings are not clear to understand for me, i am new in CMS's and i am forced to change some stuff on a old page.

Problems are:
1.
Backend seems working, half. If i enable the ext. TemplaVoila my be Page module shows me a white page.
On TV disable,
Page module, seems working but it gives me some strange error messages inside the content fields.

2. if i try to look at the front-end it gives me this exception:

> 1: PHP Runtime Deprecation Notice: Non-static method tx_ttnews_div::getSubCategories() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /var/www/projectfolder/projectfolder-typo3/typo3conf/ext/tt_news/pi/class.tx_ttnews.php
>   line 3740

Just apart from this, i read about a removed php feature in update 5.6 i was using currently.

Things i checked already:

```
-Correct PHP -v

-Database import correct

-LocalConf correct (took from live server and changed for my localhost)

-Checked install-tool and rm -rf * inside typo3temp folder
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP version combined with the versions of TYPO3 and extensions seems to be incompatible. You either need to use a different PHP version or upgrade TYPO3 and/or the extensions being used. FYI, the method being called is from a *very* old extension so although you don't say which version you're using, I assume your TYPO3 version is very old (either 6.x or even 4.x versions).

The normal recommendation would be to upgrade TYPO3 and any extensions. The less recommended alternative would be to use a different PHP version. But please be aware that remaining on older TYPO3 versions means your site may not be patched for security issues and may not be compatible with modern browsers.

Comment: yes, your right. Its a TYPO3 6.2.4. based on PHP 5.3. i was on PHP 5.6 that seems to be the problem